# $\int \arcsin(3x - 4x^3)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \arcsin(3x - 4x^3)dx$$

I think the best idea here is to use integration by parts and remove the arcsine from the integral.

$$\int \arcsin(3x - 4x^3)dx = x\arcsin(3x - 4x^4) - \int {3x(1-4x^2) \over \sqrt{1- (3x - 4x^3)^2}} dx$$

Now to integrate $\displaystyle \int {3x(1-4x^2) \over \sqrt{1- (3x - 4x^3)^2}} dx$ I tried substituting $u = 3x - 4x^3$, but then I get $\displaystyle \int {x\over \sqrt{1- u^2}} du$.

Now I need to express $x$ in terms of $u$ that is I need to solve $4x^3 - 3x + u = 0$, for which I get a [hopeless answer.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%204x%5E3%20-%203x%20%2B%20u%20%3D%200%20for%20x)

Any ideas how to solve this integrand ?

Comment: this integral leads to an elliptic function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What is an elliptic function ?

Comment: When you differentiate the $ sin^{-1} $ ... do you get $ \sqrt{1-(3x-4x^3)^{\color{red}{2}}} $ ? ... besides that $ cos 3 \theta = 4 cos^3 \theta - 3 cos \theta $ ; DHMO's suggestion $x=cos \theta $ looks like a winner.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yes I edited it properly.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I think you mean substituted for $x = \sin y$ right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\arcsin x=y\implies u=\arcsin(3x-4x^3)=\arcsin(\sin3y)$

$\implies u=n\pi+(-1)^n3y$  where $n$ is any integer.

Using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $-\dfrac\pi2\le u,y\le\dfrac\pi2$

For $n=0,u=3y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le3y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\dfrac\pi6\le y\le\dfrac\pi6$

For $n=1,u=\pi-3y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le\pi-3y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac\pi6\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

For $n=-1,u=-\pi-3y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le-\pi-3y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le-\dfrac\pi6$

Comment: I don't get the need of finding the range of the $u,y$ ?

Comment: @A---B, $$3\arcsin\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=?$$  and put $$x=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2$$  in $$\arcsin(3x-4x^3)$$

Comment: $3\arcsin \sqrt{3}/2 = \pi$ and $\arcsin 0 = 0$ no ?

Comment: @A---B, So, in this case, $$\arcsin(3x-4x^3)=\pi-3\arcsin x$$  and $$\arcsin(3x-4x^3)\ne3\arcsin x$$

Comment: I don't get it the first equality in your comment ?

Comment: @A---B, Check the values in your last comment

Comment: Ok I think you mean to say $\arcsin(3x - 4x^3) = \pi - \arcsin x$ for $x = \sqrt{3}/2$, isn't it correct ?

Comment: @A---B, $$\pi-3\arcsin x$$

Comment: No I don't get it, isn't $x = \sqrt{3}/2 = 0.886$ is in the domain of arcsine and $3\arcsin \sqrt{3}/2 = \pi$, so $\pi - \pi = 0$ and $\arcsin(3x - 4x^2) = 0 $ for $x = \sqrt{3}/2$, so everything seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

### HINT

Use the triple angle formula.

Comment: My silliness ... .  I should have seen that. Thank you.

Comment: What if $x=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2?$

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Look at the range of arcsinx , @DHMO.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem. $3x-4x^3=0$, so $\arcsin(3x-4x^3)=0$

Comment: @DHMO, Please find my answer. Please let me know if I have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

Let, $x=\sin t\implies dx=\cos t\ dt$

\begin{align*}
\int\arcsin\left(3x-4x^3\right)\ dx&=\int\arcsin\left(3\sin t-4\sin^3t\right)\cos t\ dt\\
&=\int\arcsin(\sin3t)\cos t\ dt\\
&=\int3t\cos t\ dt\\
&=3\left[t\int\cos t\ dt-\int\left\{\dfrac{d}{dt}(t)\cdot \left(\int\cos t\ dt\right)\right\}\right]\\
&=3\left[t\cdot \sin t+\cos t\right]+c\\
&=3[\arcsin x\cdot x+\cos(\arcsin x)]+c\\
&=3[x\cdot\arcsin x+\cos(\arcsin x)]+c\\
&=3x\arcsin x+3\cos\left[\arccos\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]+c\\
&=3x\arcsin x+3\sqrt{1-x^2}+c.
\end{align*}
or, you can use  direct inverse formula: $\arcsin\left(3x-4x^3\right)=3\arcsin x$.

Comment: I actually used the indirect approach. :(

Comment: yeah, I've seen it. The form is $\left(3x-4x^3\right)$ within the inverse; so you need to assume $x=$ something like $\cos\theta$ or, $\sin\theta$. If we apply direct integration by parts without assuming that, then our life will be messed up :P